# How to update multiple documents efficiently based on the value of nested property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Okay so I need to update documents based on the values of its nested property values. Suppose I have this document:

```json
{
     "_id": "61e3050a465c380aec9f56a1",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "status": "pending",
     "payment": [
             {
                  "status": "completed"
             }, 
             {
                  "status": "completed"
             }
     ]
}
```

I need to find documents where all `payment.status` is `completed` and when documents are found, then I need to update the outer `status` to completed.

I can do this in multiple queries and filter out the ones which are completed but it makes a lot of queries based on the amount of documents which I think is not efficient performance wise. So what I was thinking is if there is a way to do it in one query, may be with `Aggregate`.

Here's my implementation:

```js
let orders          = await Orders.find( {} ).populate( 'payments' );
let completedOrders = orders.filter( ( order ) => order.payments.every( ( payment ) => payment.status === 'completed' ) );

    if ( completedOrders.length !== 0 ) {
        for ( let order of completedOrders ) {
             await Orders.findByIdAndUpdate( order._id, { "status": "completed" } );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an update with aggregation pipeline. Use `$map` to create an boolean array to indicate whether `payment.status` is "completed". Then use `$allElementsTrue` with `$cond` to conditionally update the outer `status` field.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$allElementsTrue": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$payment.status",
                "as": "s",
                "in": {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$s",
                    "completed"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "then": "completed",
          "else": "$status"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/64f1RPDAr8_) for your reference.